# Autofit height for form embedded into Wix site

Tags: cognito-forms, wix.com

I've embedded a form into a Wix site.  The form has multiple pages, and I'd like the height of the page to change dynamically to fit each page, and as additional fields are expanded.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not offer a way to do this when using a Wix website. The cause of this is how Wix embeds 3rd party code. The Cognito Form is placed inside of an iframe, and we do not have a way to change the size of the containing iframe. We normally do change the size of the container holding the iframe, but we are not able to do this on a Wix website.